# Logically concatenating strings separated by hyphens

Tags: javascript, concatenation, ternary-operator

I need a single command that will concatenate 3 strings together, separating by hyphens, only if they have content.
Eg.

```
var stringOne = ["", "second", "last"];
var stringTwo = ["", second", ""];
var stringThree = ["", "", ""];
```

The results of this command should be:

> "second - last"
>
> "second"
>
> ""

Comment: [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array, and then `join` the resulting array.

Comment: @CBroe make that an answer :-)

Comment: I am trying to use ternaries but can't figure out how to precede of follow the word with a "-"

Comment: @ColeBittel I'm assuming you're doing this as some intro to coding, or you're just starting. I'd recommend avoiding ternaries, if you can't figure out how to do this without ternaries, I wouldn't recommend doing it with. What's this for?

Comment: Next time show your use of code. Anything will do, just something other than "code this for me". That is why this question is being downvoted. People here in general don't like feeling as if they are just a job shop for new users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
stringOne
.filter(function(el) {
    return el !== "";
})
.join(" - ");
```

The `filter` gets rid of all elements that are empty, `join` should be straightforward.

Comment: Worked exactly the way I was hoping. Thanks!